# exec n<&m versus exec n>&m -- based on Sobell's Linux book

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, file-descriptor

In Mark Sobell's *A Practical Guide to Linux Commands, Editors, and Shell Programming, Second Edition* he writes (p. 432):

> The <& token duplicates an input file
> descriptor; >& duplicates an output
> file descriptor.

This seems to be inconsistent with another statement on the same page:

> Use the following format to open or
> redirect file descriptor n as a
> duplicate of file descriptor m:
>
> exec n<&m

and with an example also on the same page:

```
# File descriptor 3 duplicates standard input
# File descriptor 4 duplicates standard output
exec 3<&0 4<&1
```

If >& duplicates an output file descriptor then should we not say

```
exec 4>&1
```

to duplicate standard output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example is right in practice.  The book's original explanation is an accurate description of what the POSIX standard says, but the POSIX-like shells I have handy (`bash` and `dash`, the only ones I believe are commonly seen on Linux) are not that picky.

The POSIX standard [says the same thing as the book](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_05) about input and output descriptors, and goes on to say this: for `n<&word`, "if the digits in `word` do not represent a file descriptor already open for input, a redirection error shall result".  So if you want to be careful about POSIX compatibility, you should avoid this usage.

The bash documentation also [says the same thing](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html) about `<&` and `>&`, but without the promise of an error.  Which is good, because it doesn't actually give an error.  Instead, empirically `n<&m` and `n>&m` appear to be interchangeable.  The only difference between `<&` and `>&` is that if you leave off the fd number on the left, `<&` defaults to 0 (stdin) and `>&` to 1 (stdout).

For example, let's start a shell with fd 1 pointing at a file `bar`, then try out exactly the `exec 4<&1` example, try to write to the resulting fd 4, and see if it works:

```
$ sh -c 'exec 4<&1; echo foo >&4' >bar; cat bar
foo
```

It does, and this holds using either `dash` or `bash` (or `bash --posix`) for the shell.

Under the hood, this makes sense because <& and >& are almost certainly just calling [dup2()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2), which doesn't care whether the fds are opened for reading or writing or appending or what.

[**EDIT**: Added reference to POSIX after discussion in comments.]

Comment: Thanks, especially for the reference. I'm more interested in what is supposed to work than in what may work in practice sometimes.

Comment: @Alexandros: Fair enough. Looking at the POSIX standard (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_05), which is one interpretation of "supposed to work", it says for `n<&word` that "if the digits in `word` do not represent a file descriptor already open for input, a redirection error shall result".  So if you want to be careful about POSIX compatibility, then you should avoid that usage.

Comment: In that sense, the book's description is right and its example wrong, but the title is "A *Practical* Guide", after all. =)

Comment: @Alexandros Gezerlis: OK, updated the answer to describe what POSIX says.

Comment: @Greg Price: Thanks again, I think the answer is complete now, so I've gone ahead and accepted it.

Answer (score 2):

If stdout is a tty, then it can safely be cloned for reading or writing. If stdout is a file, then it may not work. I think the example should be `4>&1`. I agree with Greg that you can both read and write the clone descriptor, but requesting a redirection with `<&` is supposed to be done with source descriptors that are readable, and expecting stdout to be readable doesn't make sense. (Although I admit I don't have a reference for this claim.)

An example may make it clearer. With this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3<&0
exec 4<&1

read -p "Reading from fd 3: " <&3
echo From fd 3: $REPLY >&2
REPLY=
read -p "Reading from fd 4: " <&4
echo From fd 4: $REPLY >&2

echo To fd 3 >&3
echo To fd 4 >&4
```

I get the following output (the stuff after the : on "Reading from" lines is typed at the terminal):

```
$ ./5878384b.sh
Reading from fd 3: foo
From fd 3: foo
Reading from fd 4: bar
From fd 4: bar
To fd 3
To fd 4
$ ./5878384b.sh < /dev/null
From fd 3:
Reading from fd 4: foo
From fd 4: foo
./5878384b.sh: line 12: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor
To fd 4
$ ./5878384b.sh > /dev/null
Reading from fd 3: foo
From fd 3: foo
./5878384b.sh: line 9: read: read error: 0: Bad file descriptor
From fd 4:
To fd 3
```

Comment: It is not immediately clear where "foo" and "bar" come from.  This is a good example, but perhaps would be clearer if you invoked the script as "printf 'foo\nbar\n' | ./5878384.sh"

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm leaning toward your viewpoint, but I was hoping for a specific reference (e.g. to the POSIX standard). I'm surprised how little authoritative material on exec and file descriptors is out there.

Comment: @William piping it in doesn't work, since the pipe only goes to stdin, but I tried to clarify which parts are input/output. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: The errors here have nothing to do with the `exec`, which is doing its job fine. Rather, they happen when you try to actually write or read to a file which was opened only for reading or writing, respectively. As a demonstration, you get the exact same errors if you write `bash -c 'echo To fd 0 >&0' < /dev/null` or `bash -c 'read -p "Reading from fd 1: " <&1' > /dev/null`.

Comment: In short, you can read only readable file descriptors, and write only writable file descriptors, and `exec` can't transmute one kind into the other no matter how you invoke it. But the question is about whether the actual `<&` versus `>&` forms in `exec` itself matter, and in bash and dash they don't, though POSIX says they are supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Mind the difference between file descriptors and IO streams such as stderr and stdout.

The redirecting operators are just redirecting IO streams via different file descriptors (IO stream handling mechanisms); they do not do any copying or duplicating of IO streams (that's what tee(1) is for).

See: [File Descriptor 101](http://www.runscripts.com/support/guides/scripting/bash/redirecting-stdout-stderr/successfully-redirecting-stdout-stderr/file-descriptor-101)

Another test to show that n<&m and n>&m are interchangeable would be "to use either style of 'n<&-' or 'n>&-' for closing a file descriptor, even if it doesn't match the read/write mode that the file descriptor was opened with" (http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/autoconf/File-Descriptors.html).